# How would you explain this difference in pointer to members of base and derived class using standard quotes?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

[demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p2I9LjqfJCM2Adci):

```
#include<iostream>
struct A { int i = 10; };
struct B : A { };

int main(){
    std::cout << "decltype(&B::i) == int A::* ? " << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<decltype(&B::i), int A::*>::value << '\n';    //#1
    A a;
    std::cout << a.*(&A::i) << '\n';

    std::cout << "decltype(&B::i) == int B::* ? "
              << std::is_same<decltype(&B::i), int B::*>::value << '\n';    //#2
    B b;
    std::cout << b.*(&B::i) << '\n';
}
```

The code prints

```
decltype(&B::i) == int A::* ? true
10
decltype(&B::i) == int B::* ? false
10
```

I used the example in [[expr.unary.op]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3), where the standard says that the type of `&B::i` is `int A::*`, but that is not normative.

Answer (score 9):

From the paragraph you link to, emphasis mine:

> If the operand is a qualified-id naming a non-static or variant member
>   `m` **of some class `C` with type `T`**, the result has type “pointer to member
>   of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`.

"Some class `C`" means it need not be the same class as the one mentioned by the qualified-id. In this case, `i` is a member of `A`, and remains a member of `A` even when named by `&B::i`. The type of `&B::i` is therefore `int A::*`, which you can verify by the test

```
std::is_same<decltype(&B::i), int A::*>::value
```

According to [[class.qual]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#1), member lookup follows the algorithm detailed in [[class.member.lookup]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.member.lookup). It is according to the rules there, which inspect the sub-object from which the member `i` comes from, that the class `C` is determined. Since `i` is a member of the sub-object `A`, the class of the pointer to member is determined to be `A`.

Comment: To add some additional commentary:  This follows on from the way that a pointer-to-member-of-base can be implicitly converted to pointer-to-member-of-derived (in contrast to the way that pointer-to-derived can be implicitly converted to pointer-to-base).

Comment: I'm not convinced by your conclusion: "Some class `C` means .... **The type of `&B::i` is therefore `int A::*`**.

Comment: @Alexander - My conclusion is backed by the member lookup algorithm. And the wording of "some class" is not coincidental.